# Evitar Captcha usando Selenium con Python

Tags: python, selenium

Quiero ver si puedo automatizar procesos en Mercado Libre como actualizar inventario, etc, usando Selenium con Python. Voy con los pasos iniciales de ir a la pagina, que de clic al botón de "
Entrar" y que ingrese el usuario en la caja de texto, sin embargo a diferencia de lo que sucede de forma tradicional, al ejecutar el script me sale un captcha. Por lo que que quisiera saber si hay una forma de "reducir" la posibilidad de que la pagina de Mercado Libre me reconozca como bot y así ya no me solicite un captcha.

O en el peor de los casos, alguna otra manera que conozcan para automatizar procesos en Mercado Libre como vendedor?

Answer (score 1):

Del lado del cliente regularmente se implementan medidas de seguridad (captcha por ejemplo) para que scripts ejecutados por bots no afecten el funcionamiento del servidor ya que por este medio se pueden hacer distintos ataques a la integridad del sistema. La manera mas sencilla que veo en Mercado Libre de automatizar este tipo de tareas es mediante el uso del API que ofrece la empresa, la puedes ver [aqui](https://developers.mercadolibre.com.mx/es_ar/guia-para-producto) en lugar de hacer uso del navegador o bien de Selenium, como los tag y la pregunta son orientadas a Selenium no podriamos decirte a ciencia cierta como implementar este metodo de automatizacion, lo que si te puedo mencionar es que puedes seguir utilizando Python para esto o bien algun cliente REST como Postman.